# Difference between deleting topics using zookeeper-shall.sh rmr brokers/topics and delete flag on kafka-topics.sh on Kafka10

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

From what I have found online and on other stack overflow posts there seem to be mainly two ways to delete topics on kafka.
The first being: a) `delete.topic.enable = true` and running `./kafka-topics.sh ---delete --topic <topicName>` 
Second way : `./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 rmr brokers/topics`

I did notice that the first method marks each topic to be deleted and over a couple of minutes the topics get deleted where as the second method deletes them instantaneously. I also noticed that on restarting the server it takes hours, is this normal? I had over 1000 topics on one broker (for testing purposes).

Answer (score 1):

The first method will create a node in zookeper `admin/delete_topics/<topic>`, and if you have enabled topic deletion as you did, a given thread in kafka broker (TopicDeletionManager), which monitor the `delete_topics` childs, will handle this, this mean deleting from zookeper but also logs from all kafka replicas, making sure you won't end up in an invalid state. Whole process is described here:
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/controller/TopicDeletionManager.scala

```
/**
 * This manages the state machine for topic deletion.
 * 1. TopicCommand issues topic deletion by creating a new admin path /admin/delete_topics/<topic>
 * 2. The controller listens for child changes on /admin/delete_topic and starts topic deletion for the respective topics
 * 3. The controller's ControllerEventThread handles topic deletion. A topic will be ineligible
 *    for deletion in the following scenarios -
  *   3.1 broker hosting one of the replicas for that topic goes down
  *   3.2 partition reassignment for partitions of that topic is in progress
 * 4. Topic deletion is resumed when -
 *    4.1 broker hosting one of the replicas for that topic is started
 *    4.2 partition reassignment for partitions of that topic completes
 * 5. Every replica for a topic being deleted is in either of the 3 states -
 *    5.1 TopicDeletionStarted Replica enters TopicDeletionStarted phase when onPartitionDeletion is invoked.
 *        This happens when the child change watch for /admin/delete_topics fires on the controller. As part of this state
 *        change, the controller sends StopReplicaRequests to all replicas. It registers a callback for the
 *        StopReplicaResponse when deletePartition=true thereby invoking a callback when a response for delete replica
 *        is received from every replica)
 *    5.2 TopicDeletionSuccessful moves replicas from
 *        TopicDeletionStarted->TopicDeletionSuccessful depending on the error codes in StopReplicaResponse
 *    5.3 TopicDeletionFailed moves replicas from
 *        TopicDeletionStarted->TopicDeletionFailed depending on the error codes in StopReplicaResponse.
 *        In general, if a broker dies and if it hosted replicas for topics being deleted, the controller marks the
 *        respective replicas in TopicDeletionFailed state in the onBrokerFailure callback. The reason is that if a
 *        broker fails before the request is sent and after the replica is in TopicDeletionStarted state,
 *        it is possible that the replica will mistakenly remain in TopicDeletionStarted state and topic deletion
 *        will not be retried when the broker comes back up.
 * 6. A topic is marked successfully deleted only if all replicas are in TopicDeletionSuccessful
 *    state. Topic deletion teardown mode deletes all topic state from the controllerContext
 *    as well as from zookeeper. This is the only time the /brokers/topics/<topic> path gets deleted. On the other hand,
 *    if no replica is in TopicDeletionStarted state and at least one replica is in TopicDeletionFailed state, then
 *    it marks the topic for deletion retry.
```

Deleting directly from zookeeper just means deleting from the orchestrator. Sure when requesting metadata, the topic aren't here anymore (well, perhaps they could from cache), but log files are not deleted (at least not right now, I assume brokers will detect the logs are invalid and delete them at some time), but you may have some incoherence on brokers (if you were in he middle of a rebalancing, you may break a lot of things). This may mean some broker will consider it deleted while some other would consider it is still there... far from ideal.

Deleting fom zookeeper (and logs from brokers) seems indeed possible from the moment, but beware, it may crate conflicts, invalid state, random error, and it may not work at all in future versions.